# Python - use logger inside function from module calling it

Tags: python, logging

Let's say I have code like this:

ModuleA.py:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('A')

def utility_func():
    logger.info('hi')
print utility_func()
```

ModuleB.py:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('B')
from ModuleA import utility_func

print utility_func()
```

When utility_func is called from within ModuleA.py I want it to use the 'A' logger, and when it's called from ModuleB.py I want it to use the 'B' logger.

Is there a way to do this?  Or a better way to set things up?

Update:

What about the idea of changing utility_func to:

```
def utility_func():
    logging.info('hi')
```

Would that bubble up to whichever log the calling code is using?

Comment: You could explicitly pass the logger in, I suppose. Note that typically you'd use `logging.getLogger(__name__)` to set the current module name.

Comment: I have 'A' and 'B' configured elsewhere to do different logging behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ended up going with.  But I'm still curious to hear if there's a more elegant way.

ModuleB.py:

```
import logging
import ModuleA

logger = logging.getLogger('B')
ModuleA.logger = logger

print ModuleA.utility_func()
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in a separate file (like utils.py)

```
def utility_func(logger):
    logger.info('hi')
```

Then in file ModuleA.py

```
import logging
import utils

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
print utility_func(logger)
```